How to export similar Sheets names into only one PDF in Excel VBA
I'm trying to export to pdf all the sheets of a workbook, where each sheet is given a name based on its content using this code:
Dim Ruta As String
Dim NombreArchivo As String
Dim hoja As Object

For Each hoja In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    NombreArchivo = "REG_PPR.004_003_" & hoja.Range("Q7") & "_" & hoja.Range("P8")
            
    hoja.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=Ruta & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=False
      
Next hoja

Thing is, multiple sheets will have similar content and therefore the same name, which results in overwriting.
I thought about checking for a file with the same name before exporting and adding a "(1)" at the end, and fuse the pdf's later with Acrobat, but maybe there's a way to check for sheets that will have the same pdf name or sheets that have similar actual sheet name, for example Sheet, Sheet (1), Sheet (2), etc.
I hope I made sense, english is not my mother tonge as you can see by the variable names.

If I understand correctly, you want to export multiple sheets from a workbook into a single PDF file, correct? In that case, simply select the desired sheets and export them as a PDF file. This will result in a single PDF file containing all the selected sheets. PS It would also be great to use English variable names as well. That would make life a lot easier for the community here.

I dont want a PDF file with all the sheets, that's fairly straightforward. I need a PDF file with all the sheets that have either same content in a cell (Q7 or P8 in my code) or consecutive sheet names( for example: one pdf that contains sheetA, sheetA (1), sheetA (2) and another one with sheetB, sheetB (1), sheetB (2)

Soory, but I do not get it. Either someone else gets what you are after or you edit your post and try to elaborate a bit more.

I adjusted the code in my answer a bit. Maybe it helps.

Based on the OP's comment maybe the following code is helpful and will give an idea how to move forward. The code will export certain sheets of the workbook into a PDF file
Dim selWs As Variant    

selWs = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(selWs).Select
ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "filename.pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

PS Based on the comment here a way to loop through the sheets and build the "string" with all the sheets which needs to be selected for printing into a PDF file.
Sub loopWorksheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Code to decide if the worksheet
    'needs to be included
    'right now every sheet is included
    dict.Add ws.Name, ws.Name
Next ws

    ' Build the "string" with the array
    ' which needs to be selected for printing into PDF
    Dim vDat As Variant
    vDat = dict.Keys

    ' Select the sheets 
    Sheets(vDat).Select
End Sub


This achieves more or less what I need, but I do not know exactly what the sheets are. In this case it would need to be something like: If name sheets looks like "Sheet" + a number, get it in the pdf

Yes, you have to build the string selWs with the names of the sheets you would like to include. I am afraid but per your post it is difficult to tell what the logic for that is.

How can I build the string with the names If I dont know if there will be 2 or 20 sheets?

You have to loop through all worksheets in the workbook  and check the criteria whether the sheet is to be included or not and then add the name of the woirksheet to the string. But as you are the one who know the criteria mentioned above it's up to you to do that.

@Antón Brea Sendón: I adjusted the answer a bit but however you need to build the logic which sheet is in and which is out.

Okay, I think I understand that code, it creates an array with all the sheets, but now how do I group the ones that have similar names?

I am afraid that's up to you. It's not that clear what similar means, at least for me. You have to build the code which decides which sheet will be added to the array.

Im gonna try to explain myself a little better but I think you also got the wrong idea right from the start. Ill have sheets named: bolt, nut, washer, but also buhsing, bushing (2), bushing (3). I want a pdf for bolt, one for nut and one for washer, but only one pdf for the bushing, bushing (2), bushing (3), etc. Some of the names will only have one sheet, but I will have some names that will have multiple sheets with the same name just adding the (2), (3), etc.
